# Loop through list of email addresses in recordset to send tailored emails

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access, outlook, recordset

I want to loop through a table and to email each user an individually tailored email with their prefix and last name.

It seems to be only emailing the first person on the list.

Design mode
[image: Screenshot in design mode]

Form mode with dummy data
[image: Screenshot in form mode with dummy data]

```vb
Private Sub SendEmail_Click()

    Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim oEmailItem As MailItem
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
    End If
    
    Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM list_of_emails")
    
    If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF = True
    
            With oEmailItem
                .To = rs!Email
                .Subject = "NKS: Test"
                .Body = "Hi " & [Prefix] & " " & [lname] & ":" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a test."
                .Send
            End With
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    rs.Close
    
    Set oEmailItem = Nothing
    Set oOutlook = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

If I remove the `On Error Resume Next`, I get the following error when I assign the recipient address (`.To = rs!Email`):

> The item has been moved or deleted.

Comment: You might want to try calling `CreateItem` within the loop, instead of using the same element over and over. Also, what happens when you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: I would add that the `On Error Resume Next` could be hiding the actual error.

Comment: Ok, I got rid of the On Error Resume Next and got a Run Time Error: "The item has been moved or deleted."

Comment: it's showing an error right at: .To = rs!Email

Comment: Since you're not changing anything in the recordset between iterations, it sounds like a mail item object cannot be reused once it has been sent (`.Send`). Therefore, as I noted in my first comment, you might want to try to move the mail-item creation (`Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)`) within the `Do ... While` loop -- it's currently before the start of the loop -- so you'll create a new mail-item for each record. Also, I would strongly suggest you step through the code with the debugger; it'll make this much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

as the comments indicate you just have a bunch of errors.  assuming you have a reference to outlook 16 object library added and Prefix and lname are columns in the list_of_emails table then:

```
Private Sub SendEmail_Click()

    Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim oEmailItem As MailItem
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    'On Error Resume Next
    'Err.Clear
    'Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
    'If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       ' Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
    'End If
    
    Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application 'open outlook before start the loop
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM list_of_emails")
    
    If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF = True
        Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'create new email for each email address
    
            With oEmailItem
                .To = rs!Email
                .Subject = "NKS: Test"
                .Body = "Hi " & rs!Prefix & " " & rs!lname & ":" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is a test."
                .Send
            End With
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    rs.Close
    
    Set oEmailItem = Nothing
    Set oOutlook = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```